# Mongo Http Configuration Class not found Error

Tags: java, spring, maven

The project is based on PetClinic . The data connects from the HANA DB and it works fine(creating tables,insert data).When I do Maven Install I am getting the following error where I am not using MongoDB. How to exclude/resolve this this.

**Trace:**

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: org.springframework.samples.petclinic.system.ProductionConfigurationTests
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 8.968 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.springframework.samples.petclinic.system.ProductionConfigurationTests
testFindAll(org.springframework.samples.petclinic.system.ProductionConfigurationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.007 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.ImportsContextCustomizer$ImportsConfiguration]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/http/MongoHttpSessionConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/session/data/mongo/config/annotation/web/http/MongoHttpSessionConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-petclinic</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <name>petclinic</name>

  <properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Web dependencies -->
    <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.6</webjars-bootstrap.version>
    <webjars-jquery-ui.version>1.11.4</webjars-jquery-ui.version>
    <webjars-jquery.version>2.2.4</webjars-jquery.version>
    <wro4j.version>1.8.0</wro4j.version>

    <cobertura.version>2.7</cobertura.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring and Spring Boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Databases - Uses HSQL by default -->

     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.db.jdbc</groupId>  
        <artifactId>ngdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency> 

    <!-- caching -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
      <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- webjars -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-jquery-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end of webjars -->

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- Spring Boot Actuator displays build-related information
              if a META-INF/build-info.properties file is present -->
            <goals>
              <goal>build-info</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <additionalProperties>
                <encoding.source>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding.source>
                <encoding.reporting>${project.reporting.outputEncoding}</encoding.reporting>
                <java.source>${maven.compiler.source}</java.source>
                <java.target>${maven.compiler.target}</java.target>
              </additionalProperties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <check />
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Spring Boot Actuator displays build-related information if a git.properties
        file is present at the classpath -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</dateFormat>
          <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties
          </generateGitPropertiesFilename>
          <failOnNoGitDirectory>false</failOnNoGitDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${wro4j.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <wroManagerFactory>ro.isdc.wro.maven.plugin.manager.factory.ConfigurableWroManagerFactory</wroManagerFactory>
          <cssDestinationFolder>${project.build.directory}/classes/static/resources/css</cssDestinationFolder>
          <wroFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.xml</wroFile>
          <extraConfigFile>${basedir}/src/main/wro/wro.properties</extraConfigFile>
          <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/less</contextFolder>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <!-- integrate maven-cobertura-plugin to project site -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cobertura.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
            <format>html</format>
          </formats>
          <check />
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

  <!-- Apache 2 license -->
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-snapshots</id>
      <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>spring-milestones</id>
      <name>Spring Milestones</name>
      <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**ProductionConfigurationTests:**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.samples.petclinic.vet.VetRepository;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ComponentScan({"org.springframework*"})
@EntityScan("com.springframework*")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springframework*")
public class ProductionConfigurationTests {

    @Autowired
    private VetRepository vets;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
        vets.findAll();
        vets.findAll(); // served from cache
    }
}
```

I tried downloading and added the spring-session-data.jar but it is still giving the same error. Kindly guide as I am new to this Maven/Spring

Thanks

Comment: Add your `pom.xml`

Comment: lookup for a place where `MongoHttpSessionConfiguration` text is used

Comment: Check your source code for that annotation, you may want to post the entire stack trace also

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I cannot find this .Thatsy I am confused..

Comment: take a look at ProductionConfigurationTests. And don't mind to comment all the test cases for the time being. Though this seems more of a debugging question and not having sufficient details.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati: When I comment ProductionConfigurationTests code build success. but any suggestion why this error.  I added the code

Comment: You are scanning the Spring packages! Do not do this, it's trying to load all the autoconfigurations/configurations it's find and this is why you are getting the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is causing the issue. You are trying to scan the Spring packages which contains a lot of `Autoconfiguration` and other `Configuration` classes which the context is trying to load. You should never do this.

All you should need to do for your test is this add

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

You could also use a `@DataJpaTest`

The `SpringBootTest` will use your `SpringBootApplication` class which will component scan for you, it should be placed the root of your package structure, and it will scan the child packages for you.

Comment: Thank you Darren :) It helped